# How to install syntax highlight package minted on Windows 7?

Tags: installing, miktex, windows, minted

I followed the instruction from this link: http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted/

[image]

Firstly, I install Python 2.7, then create a folder named `Scripts` in the directory:

```
C:\Python27
```

So I got `C:\Python27\Scripts`
Then I create a file named `pygmentize.cmd` with the content:

```
@echo off
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27
%PYTHONPATH%\python.exe %PYTHONPATH%Scripts\pygmentize %*
```

At this point, I already set the `path` environment variable to `C:\Python27` and `C:\Python27\Scripts`.
Next I installed `setuptools-0.6c11.win32-py2.7.exe (md5)` from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools
And install `Pygments` with the following command

```
easy_install Pygments
```

Next I include the line `\usepackage{minted}` to let TexMaker do the installation.

Inside TexMaker, I also change the `PdfLaTex` option to:
`pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

Then I tried out a simple example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minted}{python}
    def boring(args = None):
    pass
    \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

And the compiler generated these error:

```
!Emergency stop.<read 2> \TestAppExists{pygmentize}
!==> Fatal error occured, no output PDF file produced!
```

I guessed the `pygmentize` was not installed properly so TexMaker wasn't able to run it. I read the instruction over, and couldn't figure out what could cause these errors? Has anyone done it before could share me some lights?

Thank you,

Comment: Python 3.4 and newer as well as Python 2.7.9 and newer come with `pip` included, which makes installing Pygments a lot easier! This question is now more or less obsolete.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On my Windows 7 system, the following got things working:

- [Download and install Python 2.7.2](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.2/)
- [Download and install distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute#installation-instructions)
- Add `C:\Python27\Scripts` to the Windows path (I also added `C:\Python27` for general convenience)
- At the Command Prompt, do `easy_install Pygmentize`

That is it install-wise: the current Pygmentize *does* come with a Windows executable. You can test this by doing `pygmentize -V` at the Command Prompt.

What I then found is that the test that `minted` uses for Pygmentize on Windows is broken. So I used the lines

```
\newcommand\TestAppExists[3]{#2}
\usepackage{minted}
```

to bypass the test (this basically forces the TRUE branch). The example document then compiles fine.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Without the fix for `\TestAppExists` I get TeX asking for `\@apppathifexists=`, which does not much good!

Comment: @Chan: Just to point out that I'm using TeX Live 2010. I don't think this should make too much difference to the result, although there are occasional differences in file handling between TeX Live and MiKTeX.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I think I got all the steps set up correctly, except the fix for `\newcommand`. I wonder where should I add these two lines? inside my .tex or inside the `minted.sty`. I added in my .tex and I got another error.

Comment: I tried out your solution on Ubuntu and it worked perfectly. I still couldn't figure out why it was broken on Windows :(.

Comment: @Chan: On my system, I added the `\newcommand` part in the main `.tex` file, just before loading `minted`. That was because my initial trial failed to work, with TeX waiting for some kind of keyboard input. The Pygmentize installation itself went fine, as checked at the Command Prompt using `pymgmetize -V`.

Comment: I ran pygmentize -V, and the output was: `Pygments version 1.4, (c) 2006-2008 by Georg Brandl`. So I guess it was installed correctly. By the way, do you have your `pygmentize.cmd` in the `Scripts` folder? And what do you have in your `minted` folder? I only have `minted.sty`, does it sounds reasonable?

Comment: @Chan: No, I have `pygmentize.exe` and `pygmentize-script.py`. Just `minted.sty` is entirely correct for the `minted` side of things.

Comment: That's exactly what I got. Don't know why keep getting these errors: `! Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package`

Comment: The test minted uses was only tested on Windows XP, where it works fine. Windows 7 apparently changes its parsing of batch commands. Unfortunately, I have to maintain the “not supported” status since I haven’t got Windows.

Comment: When I do "easy_install Pygmentize" then I get "Couldn't find index page for 'Pygmentize' (maybe misspelled?)". Does anyone know what's going wrong there?

Comment: Found the problem. Under my Windows it was "easy_install Pygments" and then I had to do "pygmentize.exe -V" to see the output.

Comment: If you install pygments with pip (see my answer below) everything works fine and there is no need for a workaround.

Comment: Maybe this answer could be update to no longer recommend Python 2? https://python3statement.org/

Answer (score 25):

Python 3.4 and newer come with the package manager `pip` already included:
http://docs.python.org/3.4/whatsnew/3.4.html

Setting up `minted`+`Pygments` has therefore become very easy:

1. Install the latest Python 3.x (PATH can be set during installation).
2. From a normal command prompt, run `python -m pip install -U pygments`. This will create a `pygmentize.exe` in the Pythons Scripts directory.
3. You are done. Using `\usepackage{minted}` in `.tex` files should now work.

Of course, pdfLaTeX (or whatever engine/format you use) still has to be called with the `-shell-escape` option.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/Pygments/

Answer (score 13):

The problem might be due to issues with setuptools (for example with UAC).

Here is an installation procedure which is working for me:

1. Install Python 2.7
2. [Install distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute#installation-instructions) (replacement for setuptools because it is buggy and no more maintained)
3. Add `C:\Python27\Scripts` to your PATH
4. Install pip: `easy_install pip`
5. Install pygments: `pip install pygments`

These steps create a `pygmentize.exe`, so there is no need to create the batch file.

Answer (score 4):

Re-installing `minted` fixed the issue. To uninstall a package in MikTex, go to Package Manager (Admin). Reinstall minted under TexMaker, after that I don't even need the 
`\newcommand\TestAppExists[3]{#2}`. Just make sure you add the scripts `pygmentize.cmd` to the `C:\Python27\Scripts\` with the content:

```
@echo off
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27
%PYTHONPATH%\python.exe %PYTHONPATH%\Scripts\pygmentize %*
```

**Note**: The one in the instruction document missed a `\` after `%PYTHON%`. Further, this solution only works under Windows environment, for Linux variants, you have to go with Joseph Wright's solution.

Answer (score 3):

I have Windows 10 and I think [Joseph's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23466/101651) should be updated.

In the following there is what I've just done to install Pigmentize, I don't know if there are some unnecessary steps but, in my case, this worked.

*Dowload Python*

I've downloaded and installed the latest release of [Python for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).

*Install setuptools*

Since `distribute` is deprecated now, I've used `setuptools`,
in the command prompt, I've run (see [here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/)):

```
python -m pip install -U pip setuptools
```

*Add Python paths to system paths*

[In my system path I've added](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-add-new-folder-my-system-path):

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts
```

and also:

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36
```

*Install pygments*

In the command prompt, I've run:

```
easy_install pygments
```

*Restart Windows*

After restarting Windows all works.

Answer (score 2):

So this is a bit late, but I got everything to work on Windows 7 and I can compile and create my pdf within TeXworks using MiKTeX. (I apologize for improper formatting. Doing this late at night and have not done this before, but I wanted to type it somewhere before I forget)

1. Install Python 2.7
2. Install setuptools-0.6c11.win32-py2.7.exe
3. Add C:\Python27\Scripts to your PATH (just google how to do this if you don't know how)
4. Navigate to your Scripts folder and run "easy_install Pygments" in the command prompt
5. Make a file called "pygmentize.cmd" in the Scripts folder with the contents:
   @echo off
   set PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27
   %PYTHONPATH%\python.exe %PYTHONPATH%\Scripts\pygmentize %*

As of now, if you run "pdflatex --shell-escape myFileName.tex" in the command prompt it will work.  If you want it to work within TeXworks (and I assume other similar programs), you have to make one extra step.

1. Click edit-->preferences, then go to the Typesetting tab.  Click the "+" and add your Scripts directory ("C:\Python27\Scripts")

Now it works! Yay! With this set of steps, the \newcommand\TestAppExists[3]{#2} is not needed.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)