# Conflict between packages auto-pst-pdf and minted?

Tags: minted, auto-pst-pdf

I have tried to create a document using the pdfLaTeX engine which includes graphics generated by PSTricks and resorts to the package [`auto-pst-pdf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/auto-pst-pdf). Everything went right until I used the package minted; as soon as this was included, `auto-pst-pdf` could not create the `-autopp.dvi` file and the ensuing `-pics.pdf` file. Everything about the package `minted` seems to go right either with or without including `auto-pst-pdf`, so it seems to me that the latter has some conflict with the former. Anyone knows what is going on here?

Thanks so much for your attention and assistance.

I am appending an MWE right below as suggested by texlearner:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
%\usepackage{minted}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
\psset{fillstyle=solid}
\psscalebox{0.75}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-5.25,-5.25)(5.25,5.25)%
  \pscircle*[linecolor=cyan]{5}
  \psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=lightgray,gridlabels=0pt]
  \Huge\sffamily\bfseries
  \rput(-4.5,4.5){A} \rput(4.5,4.5){B}
  \rput(-4.5,-4.5){C}\rput(4.5,-4.5){D}
  \rput(0,0){auto-pst-pdf}
  \rmfamily
  \rput(0,-3.8){PSTricks}
  \rput(0,3.8){\LaTeX}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

With WinEdt 6.0 and on MikTeX 2.9, as long as the inclusion of `minted` is commented, `pdflatex` with `-shell-escape` generates the corresponding one-page long PDF. As soon as `minted` is effectively included, no PDF is created.

Herbert has provided an answer (to be found below) which solves the problem in what `minted` is concerned. Nonetheless, I have found a strange behavior when some [PSTricks-based packages](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi) are included jointly with the base package  `pstricks`. As an MWE let me suggest the following code:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

    \usepackage{ifpdf}
    \ifpdf
       \usepackage{minted}
       \usemintedstyle{friendly}
       \newminted{latex}{linenos=true,mathescape}
   \else
       \usepackage{pstricks,pst-blur,pst-circ,pst-grad,pst-node,
                    pst-gantt,pst-eucl,pst-3d,pst-solides3d,pst-lens,
                    pst-coxeterp,pst-coxcoor,pst-rubans,pst-eps,
                    pst-dbicons,pst-light3d,pst-tree,pst-sigsys,
                    pst-text,pst-slpe}
       \usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-optexp,pst-optic,pst-plot,pst-3dplot}
   \fi

    \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

    \newcommand{\pstricksplot}{%
             \begin{postscript}
             \psset{fillstyle=solid}
             \psscalebox{0.75}{%
             \begin{pspicture}(-5.25,-5.25)(5.25,5.25)%
             \pscircle*[linecolor=cyan]{5}
             \psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=lightgray,gridlabels=0pt]
             \Huge\sffamily\bfseries
             \rput(-4.5,4.5){A} \rput(4.5,4.5){B}
             \rput(-4.5,-4.5){C}\rput(4.5,-4.5){D}
             \rput(0,0){auto-pst-pdf}
             \rmfamily
             \rput(0,-3.8){PSTricks}
             \rput(0,3.8){\LaTeX}
             \end{pspicture}}
             \end{postscript}
             }

   \pagestyle{empty}

   \begin{document}

   \pstricksplot

   A few lines with minted:

   \begin{latexcode}
      \psplot[linecolor=#1,plotstyle=curve,
              linewidth=1.25\pslinewidth,linestyle=#2,
              plotpoints=10000]{#3}{#4}{1 div x #5\space mul #6\space add}
      % Parameter 5 is the resonance frequency  $\omega_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}\,\cdot$
      % Parameter 6 is the time constant $\tau=RC\,.$
   \end{latexcode}

  The same PSTricks code as above the ``minted'' lines.

  \pstricksplot

  \end{document}
```

Now, the strange behavior is related to the inclusion of any of the packages `pstricks-add`, `pst-optexp`, `pst-optic`, `pst-plot`, `pst-3dplot`. I have included the PSTricks-based packages in two different bunches in order to emphasize this point: if I comment the corresponding line, everything goes fine; but if they are effectively included, the command `\pstricksplot` right above the end of the document does not lead to a graphic in the PDF. I use graphics intensively and PSTricks has proved most convenient for my needs, hence my including all those pst- packages.

Thanks so much for your assistance and attention.

Comment: As such there is no known issues regarding the auto-pst-pdf mentioned in the package userguide at ctan.org http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/auto-pst-pdf May be report the bug to the author of the package 
Will Robertson. Also post a minimum working example(MWE) to make sure its due to auto-pst-pdf and minted conflict.

Comment: Dear texlearner, thanks so much for your reply. I am appending a MWE. On WinEdt 6.0 and with MikTeX 2.9 it generates a 1 page pdf if minted is not included, but none if it is. The inclusion of minted is commmented in the LaTeX code below.

Comment: can you please mark herbert's reply as answer if it satisfies your original question. you can always get more answers as many people visit

Comment: Done. Thanks for letting me know about this. It is my first "active" time around...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use it this way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage{minted}
  \usemintedstyle{friendly} 
  \newminted{latex}{linenos=true,mathescape} 
\else
  \usepackage{pstricks-add}
\fi
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{postscript} 
\psset{fillstyle=solid}
\psscalebox{0.75}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-5.25,-5.25)(5.25,5.25)%
  \pscircle*[linecolor=cyan]{5}
  \psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=lightgray,gridlabels=0pt]
  \Huge\sffamily\bfseries
  \rput(-4.5,4.5){A} \rput(4.5,4.5){B}
  \rput(-4.5,-4.5){C}\rput(4.5,-4.5){D}
  \rput(0,0){auto-pst-pdf}
  \rmfamily
  \rput(0,-3.8){PSTricks}
  \rput(0,3.8){\LaTeX}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{postscript} 

and now the minted part:

\ifpdf
   \begin{latexcode}
      \psplot[linecolor=#1,plotstyle=curve,
              linewidth=1.25\pslinewidth,linestyle=#2,
              plotpoints=10000]{#3}{#4}{1 div x #5\space mul #6\space add}
      % Parameter 5 is the resonance frequency  $\omega_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}\,\cdot$
      % Parameter 6 is the time constant $\tau=RC\,.$
   \end{latexcode}
\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear Herbert, thanks so much for your reply. This seemed to solve the problem in what minted was concerned, but then I found out that there was a problem when I tried to include more PSTricks-based packages. Simply including pstricks-add together with pstricks makes that a LaTeX command that has been defined in the preamble and that includes only a pspicture environment is obliterated after a minted environment has been compiled. That is, there is no corresponding picture in the pdf. I could append a MWE, but I'm not sure about how to do it otherwise than by editing my original question.

Comment: @Marcos: edit your original question or extend it.

Comment: @Marcos: see my edit. And by the way: it is totally nonsense to load all packages you are knowing. And, of course, pstricks-add should _always_ be the last PSTricks related package.

Comment: @Marcos: loading all of your listed packages, my example will also work.

Comment: Thanks so much again. I have checked and, sure, it is the answer. I am still trying to see what is going on with hyperref. I am loading all those pst- packages because, except for two of those included, I really need them for the document I am working on.

Comment: @Marcos: edited your last example so that I can see how do you load hyperref and what's going wrong

Comment: I have solved the cross-references issue. It was actually about the interaction of cleveref with hyperref, and it was my fault since I was loading cleveref before hyperref, whereas they are to be loaded in the reverse order -- just as stated in the cleveref documentation. Thank you very much for your attention and interest. I have deleted my remarks on this issue from my original question.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are working on Windows 7, In the minted package user manual at ctan.org http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted, there is known issue on window 7, its workaround is also included in the manual. [How to install syntax highlight package minted on Windows 7?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23458/how-to-install-syntax-highlight-package-minted-on-windows-7)

Incase you need some support on minted package, try contacting the http://code.google.com/p/minted/issues/list

I am sure that auto-pst-pdf does not have any conflicts with minted. Instead check with minted  package.

By the way you can also include auto-pst-pdf automatically by giving the options [pdf] in the pstricks as follows \usepackage[pdf]{pstricks} when using with pdflatex engine

Comment: Thank you so much for your attention. Actually, I am working on Windows XP. I have checked the documentation of both packages, and nothing is said about this. Just in case, I have also tried using the option [pdf] for pst, but to no avail. Have you tried compiling the MWE I have appended with the inclusion of minted uncommented?