# TeXworks expl3.sty error

Tags: minted, texworks

I am trying to check if `minted` is already installed in my computer. I successfully installed `Python`, `distributed.py` and `pip` as instructed in [this tutorial](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23466/22271). I am now trying to test the new package with the sample:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{minted}

\setsansfont{Calibri}
\setmonofont{Consolas}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{
  \sffamily\textcolor[rgb]{0.5,0.5,0.5}{\scriptsize\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}

\begin{minted}[mathescape,
           linenos,
           numbersep=5pt,
           gobble=2,
           frame=lines,
           framesep=2mm]{csharp}
  string title = "This is a Unicode π in the sky"
  /*
  Defined as $\pi=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{P_n}{d}$ where $P$ is the perimeter
  of an $n$-sided regular polygon circumscribing a
  circle of diameter $d$.
  */
  const double pi = 3.1415926535
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

I tried generating the sample in my TeXworks but the log file says that `expl3.sty not found` even though when I checked the Package Manager, it is present.

Here is the complete log file for more information:

```
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (MiKTeX 2.9)
    entering extended mode
    (C:/Users/Username/Documents/LaTeX/minted.tex
    LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
    Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
    abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
    croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
    lician, german, german-x-2009-06-19, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
    ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, lao, latin, lat
    vian, lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerm
    an, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, 
    romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swis
    sgerman, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, u
    senglishmax, welsh, loaded.
    ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
    Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
    ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
    ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.sty"
    ======================================================================
    starting package maintenance...
    installation directory: C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
    package repository: http://ctan.cdpa.nsysu.edu.tw/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
    lightweight database digest: 2b12adf201b76e6cb772a57dc48b7601
    pdflatex.EXE: Unknown archive file size.
    pdflatex.EXE: Data: expl3
    ======================================================================


    ! LaTeX Error: File `expl3.sty' not found.

    Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
    or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
```

Comment: Does this error only occur with Minted? The package doesn’t use `expl3` directly anywhere. I don’t know whether it’s used indirectly anywhere.

Comment: Nothing to do with `minted`, rather `fontspec` requires `expl3`. However, it's not really a LaTeX error at all: the problem is that MiKTeX is failing to download and install on the fly correctly. I would try using the MiKTeX Package Manager to pick a different source and re-try installing the `l3kernel` bundle (which contains `expl3`).

Comment: Thank you for the comments!

@JosephWright: I already re-installed `l3kernel` but how do I 'pick a different source'?

Comment: In the Package Manager, from the Repository menu, Change Package Repository.

Comment: @JosephWright: Thank you for the guide. I already did what you said and I think my database was updated. I am now running my `.tex` file in cmd using `pdflatex -shell-escape file.tex` but the error `! Package minted Error: You must have 'pygmentize' installed to use this package.` appears. I haven't seen any legit and working solution to this one regarding Win7 though :( Do you know a solution to this one, Sir?

Comment: @thekalaban `minted` relies on an external program (`pygmentize`) based on Python. However the documentation says that Windows in not really supported by `minted` (section 2.4); you may try installing Python and `pygmentize` as suggested there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(CW answer from comment; it's really a Windows problem, rather than TeX)

`minted` relies on an external program (`pygmentize`) based on Python. However the documentation says that Windows in not really supported by `minted` (section 2.4 of the manual); you may try installing Python and `pygmentize` as suggested there,