# XML with Listings: Different colors for attributes and elements

Tags: listings, color, xml

How can I make every attribute name in color X and every element name in color Y without adding keywords and stuff?

What I did so far:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{myXML}
{
    morestring=[b]",
    morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
    morekeywords={
        name,
        type,
        targetNamespace,
        element,
        xmlns,
        xsd,
        s0,
        soap,
        http
    }
}

\lstdefinestyle{xmlStyle}{
    language=myXML,
    stringstyle=\color{mygreen},
    identifierstyle=\color{blue},
    keywordstyle=\color{mymauve},
}
```

What this results in:

[image]

As you can see, some of the element names (like xsd:something) are mauve instead of blue because they appear both as element and attribute name. Same with `binding` and `element`

Comment: Is `minted` an option for you?

Comment: Is there an easy way to do this with Windows?

Comment: If you have installed pygmentize, the answer is yes. See: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23466/5239](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23458/how-to-install-syntax-highlight-package-minted-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if the problem is unsolvable with the listings-package. As recommended by @Marco Daniel I switched to the minted-package which works like a charm.

The installation was complicated but the instructions here helped me.

[How to install syntax highlight package minted on Windows 7?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23458/how-to-install-syntax-highlight-package-minted-on-windows-7)

What all of these instructions where missing: You need to reboot after installing everything (at least that worked for me).

If you use TeXlipse (like me) and want to add the `-shell-escape` flag

```
Rightclick on Project > Properties > Latex Project Properties > Setup build tools... >
Select 'PdfLatex program' > Edit > Insert '-shell-escape' somewhere before '%input'
```

After that you can actually use minted.

I put this somewhere in the beginning (preamble) to make a reusable xml-style

```
\newminted[xml]{xml}{
    bgcolor = mygray,
    fontfamily = tt,
    fontsize = \scriptsize,
    gobble = 1,
    samepage
}
```

In my actual content I embedded XML like this

```
\begin{listing}[!ht]
  \begin{xml}
    <element attribute="value" />
  \end{xml}
  \caption[Test]{Just a test caption}
  \label{lst:test}
\end{listing}
```

The listing environment is to reference this piece of code later. If you are using `\autoref{}` you might find this helpful

```
\providecommand*{\listingautorefname}{Listing}
```

Thanks to Marco Daniel for showing me the minted-package :)