# Problem on minted package on Windows 7

Tags: minted, pygments

I exactly followed the instruction and I also tried those solutions on this link: [How to install syntax highlight package minted on Windows 7?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23458/how-to-install-syntax-highlight-package-minted-on-windows-7) Unfortunately, I could not run `minted` package on Texmaker. I have got error when it is compiled. Any idea about this issue?

```
runsystem(del transfer*report.aex)...executed.
runsystem(for ^%i in (pygmentize.exe pygmentize.bat pygmentize.cmd) do set >tra
nsfer*report.aex <nul: /p x=^%~$PATH:i>>transfer*report.aex)...executed.
\@appexistsfile=\read3
! Emergency stop.<read 3>
l.41
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
```

[image]

Content of `C:\Python27\Scripts\pygmentize.cmd`:

```
@echo off
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27
%PYTHONPATH%\Scripts\pygmentize.exe %*
```

Windows Path is also done as:

```
C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts
```

Also I can see by SET command on cmd path has `C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts`.

On command line the `pygmentize` looks installed correctly as:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pygmentize -V
Pygments version 1.6, (c) 2006-2013 by Georg Brandl.
```

Texmaker compilation option is also changed as:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

I also tried to uninstall and install minted package over "MikTex 2.9" -> "Package Manager".
But there is not any improvement.

Edit : 
I realized that it is working in a separate  latex file as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{c}
int main() 
{
    printf("hello, world");
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

So it should be there some package conflicts or stg like how can I understand it, any idea?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

***Edit**: According to OP the missing “s” was just a typo here in question (but made twice then …).*

The `pygmentize.cmd` is never found because of a typo you did in the Windows path – you forgot an “s” at the very end, it’s `C:\Python27\Scripts`.

BTW: When `pygmentize.exe` is really also in `C:\Python27\Scripts` you do not need  `pygmentize.cmd` at all as long as it is in this same folder.

Comment: This is not the case! Because I just mistype it here not in real scenario. Furthermore, without pygmentize.cmd or with pygmentize.cmd, it is giving the same error. Any other idea ?

Comment: Did you perhaps forget to add the command line option `--shell-escape` in Texmaker settings?

Comment: I have done it before, I think there is a conflict with some other packages or my template but I could not figure it out. If I only put my example in a separate latex file there is not any problem. But with my normal tex file doesnt work. No idea :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem.
Removing all spaces from the name of the TeX file fixed it.