# How can I replicate the syntax-highlighting style of the Kate editor?

Tags: listings, code

I am trying to add a `java` and `c++` code in a `LaTeX` document. I am using `listings` package and I will define a different style for each language using `\lstdefinestyle{myStyle}{<options>}`. What I am trying to achieve is the colouring and the emphasis that the editor `Kate` uses, as shown in the next image

[image]

Look for instance the different styles for comments. When a comment starts with `//` it's gray, while when it's enclosed between `/**comment*/` it's green.

Or perhaps the different colors for keywords : `int` is dark blue while `static final int` is brighter.

Also take a look at the numbers: They are yellow. Or for instance the strings are red. I've tried to reproduce those but I wasn't able to do this(the numbers) or the purple methods that are used.

For instance I can't define different coloring for different comments or key words. I can't color at all the numbers and the `get***` methods. MY code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{listinggray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}

\lstdefinestyle{JavaStyle}{
        backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor},
    tabsize=4,
%   rulecolor=,
    language=Java,      % choose the language of the code
        basicstyle=\scriptsize,     % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
        upquote=true,
        aboveskip={1.5\baselineskip},
        columns=fixed,
        showstringspaces=false,
        extendedchars=false,
        breaklines=true,
        prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
        frame=single,
        numbers=left,
        showtabs=false,
        showspaces=false,
        showstringspaces=false,
        identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
        keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
        %commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.026,0.112,0.095},
        commentstyle=\itshape\color{green!40!black},
        stringstyle=\itshape\color{red!90!black},
        numberstyle=\itshape\color{yellow!50!black}
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{lstlisting}[style=JavaStyle]
  int[] ones = {1,1};
    int points = 10;
    int[] region = new int[points];
    int timeTicks;
    int totalTime;
    int LiveTime = 0;
    int totcount;
    int evType = 1; //The Type ID for these kinds of events
    SimpleDateFormat today = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat now = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");

    Map<String,KmaxHist> histograms = new HashMap<String,KmaxHist>();

    static final int evSize = 6;//The num of parameters per event of this type
    static final int BUF_SIZE = evSize*1000;// Buffer size  
    static final int LP_MEM_TOP = 0xFFFF00;//Memory size 16MB   
    static final int READ_START = LP_MEM_TOP  -  BUF_SIZE;//We start the read/write pointer 1 buffer before the end

    int[] blkData = new int[BUF_SIZE];  
    /**
    * The 'init' method is executed at compile time.
    */
    public void init(KmaxToolsheet toolsheet) {
        tlsh = toolsheet;//Save this reference for use in the toolsheet

        dev = tlsh.getKmaxDevice("DEV1");
        dataField = tlsh.getKmaxWidget("$R_DATA");
        countField = tlsh.getKmaxWidget("$R_COUNT");
        liveTime = tlsh.getKmaxWidget("LIVE_TIME");//Live Time
        realTime = tlsh.getKmaxWidget("REAL_TIME");//Real Time
        deadTime = tlsh.getKmaxWidget("DEAD_TIME");//Dead Time
        hist1 = tlsh.getKmaxHist("DATA1");
        hist2 = tlsh.getKmaxHist("DATA2");
        hist3 = tlsh.getKmaxHist("DATA3");
        hist4 = tlsh.getKmaxHist("DATA4");
        hist5 = tlsh.getKmaxHist("DATA5");
        hist6 = tlsh.getKmaxHist("DATA6");
        histoLowX = tlsh.getKmaxHist("HIST_LOW_X");
        histoLowY = tlsh.getKmaxHist("HIST_LOW_Y");

        histograms.put("DATA1", hist1);
                histograms.put("DATA2", hist2);
        histograms.put("DATA3", hist3);
 \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

and the output is

[image]

Any idea on how to reproduce the code in the first image?

Comment: Something to start with: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34896 But this will also colour digits in comments.

Comment: I'd consider using `minted` for more complex stuff, but that's just because I'm too lazy to hack `listings`. :-)

Comment: @1010011010 : I've install `minted` but I can't get `pygmentize` to install. I've installed `texlive-latex-extra` and `python-pygments` but I can't get it to work... Perhaps because I don't know how to run pdf text with shell escape in Kile... I don't want to use a terminal, I want to add this command to the quick build!

Comment: @1010011010 : Even if I use `pdflatex -shell-escape chapter7` it still doens't work. I get `! LaTeX Error: File `l3unicode-data.def' not found`

Comment: Have you tried the instructions in this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23466/44160 ? This worked for me.

Comment: @1010011010 : I've seen this question, but I am using `ubuntu`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea on how to reproduce the code in the first image?

Yes, I've got a few ideas, see below.

However, highlighting numbers (including hexadecimal expressions, such as `0xFFFF00`) in a robust way is, though not impossible, notoriously difficult. If you're determined to implement a solution, you could use my answer to [How to highlight all words of the form [0-9][A-Za-z0-9]* immediately following an equal sign?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81676/how-to-highlight-all-words-of-the-form-0-9a-za-z0-9-immediately-following-a) as a starting point.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lstautodedent} 
\definecolor{listinggray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}

\lstdefinestyle{JavaStyle}{
    language=Java,      % choose the language of the code
    deletekeywords={new,public},
    keywords=[2]{HashMap,Map,SimpleDateFormat,String},
    keywords=[3]{getKmaxDevice,getKmaxWidget,getKmaxHist,init},
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color[RGB]{69,97,189},
    keywordstyle=[2]{\color{cyan}},
    keywordstyle=[3]\color[RGB]{137,77,155},
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{green!60!black},
    moredelim=[l][\itshape\color{gray}]{//}, %<--- overrides line-comment style
    stringstyle=\color[RGB]{192,8,8},
    numberstyle=\itshape\color{yellow!50!black},
%   backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor},
    tabsize=4,
%   rulecolor=,
    upquote=true,
    aboveskip={1.5\baselineskip},
    columns=fixed,
    showstringspaces=false,
    extendedchars=false,
    breaklines=true,
    prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
    frame=single,
    numbers=left,
    showtabs=false,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    autodedent,%<--- removes indentation
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{lstlisting}[style=JavaStyle]
    int[] ones = {1,1};
    int points = 10;
    int[] region = new int[points];
    int timeTicks;
    int totalTime;
    int LiveTime = 0;
    int totcount;
    int evType = 1; //The Type ID int for these kinds of events
    SimpleDateFormat today = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat now = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");

    Map<String,KmaxHist> histograms = new HashMap<String,KmaxHist>();

    static final int evSize = 6;//The num of parameters per event of this type
    static final int BUF_SIZE = evSize*1000;// Buffer size  
    static final int LP_MEM_TOP = 0xFFFF00;//Memory size 16MB   
    static final int READ_START = LP_MEM_TOP  -  BUF_SIZE;//We start the read/write pointer 1 buffer before the end

    int[] blkData = new int[BUF_SIZE];  
    /**
    * The 'init' method is executed at compile time.
    */
    public void init(KmaxToolsheet toolsheet) {
        tlsh = toolsheet;//Save this reference for use in the toolsheet

        dev = tlsh.getKmaxDevice("DEV1");
        dataField = tlsh.getKmaxWidget("$R_DATA");
        countField = tlsh.getKmaxWidget("$R_COUNT");
        liveTime = tlsh.getKmaxWidget("LIVE_TIME");//Live Time
        realTime = tlsh.getKmaxWidget("REAL_TIME");//Real Time
        deadTime = tlsh.getKmaxWidget("DEAD_TIME");//Dead Time
        hist1 = tlsh.getKmaxHist("DATA1");
        hist2 = tlsh.getKmaxHist("DATA2");
        hist3 = tlsh.getKmaxHist("DATA3");
        hist4 = tlsh.getKmaxHist("DATA4");
        hist5 = tlsh.getKmaxHist("DATA5");
        hist6 = tlsh.getKmaxHist("DATA6");
        histoLowX = tlsh.getKmaxHist("HIST_LOW_X");
        histoLowY = tlsh.getKmaxHist("HIST_LOW_Y");

        histograms.put("DATA1", hist1);
                histograms.put("DATA2", hist2);
        histograms.put("DATA3", hist3);
 \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```