# Minted language "text" doesn't obey to breaklines

Tags: line-breaking, minted, pygments

I'm trying to render code inline using `minted`.
Given that it can be *any* code, I'm using the `text` language.

However, I've realized it doesn't obey to line breaks, as other language do.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{minted}


\begin{document}
Here is a veeeeeryyyyy veeeeeryyyyy loooooooooong \texttt{mintinline} with a break,
\mintinline[breaklines, breakanywhere]{python}{very_long_class_name} because it uses the \textbf{Python} minted language.


Here is a veeeeeryyyyy veeeeeryyyyy loooooooooong \texttt{mintinline} with a break,
\mintinline[breaklines, breakanywhere]{text}{very_long_class_name} using the \textbf{text} minted language.
    
    
\end{document}
```

And here is the output :

[image: MWE output]

**How can I use the `text` language and still have line breaks ?**

Comment: may be try smt like here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200310/break-lines-in-minted-environment?rq=1

Comment: Not useful IMO. The problem is that breaklines seems to be language-dependant (since using the `Python` language triggers the break, while `text` does not).

Comment: Issue has been filed in the minted Github : https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/311