# ShareLatex - using minted in subfiles

Tags: minted, sharelatex, subfiles

I am using ShareLatex with each of my sections split into subfiles, and now needs to insert some source code. In doing so i have used the package minted which works fine if i keep my code example in the main file. But when i move the same code example into one of the subfiles i get the error:
 Package minted Error: Missing Pygments.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: Is this topic http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23458/how-to-install-syntax-highlight-package-minted-on-windows-7 helpful?

Comment: No, minted is by default installed in ShareLatex. I found that it works fine when compiling the whole document. But the problem arises when compiling individual subfiles containing minted, then i get the error, and the code does not show up?

Answer (score 1):

In order for minted to work properly on ShareLaTeX, the compiled file must be in the root directory of the project, i.e. it cannot be stored in a folder.