# Using minted within a subfile to list a code in a subdirectory

Tags: minted, subfiles, multiple-files, directory

I am using Windows as OS and TeXstudio as editor.

My project has the following structure:

```
-project
    -main.tex
    -chapter1
        -chapter1.tex
        -bibgraf.bib
        -figures
        -listings
    -chapter2
        -chapter2.tex
        -bibgraf.bib
        -figures
        -listings
```

I am using the `subfiles` package in order to compile independently the various chapters of my document. I would like to use the `minted` package in each `chapterN.tex` file in order to list the codes present in the `listings` subdirectory of the `chapterN` directory.

I am not sure whether this is actually possible with `minted`, because it seems that it can only work with the root document directory according to what I have found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311146/sharelatex-using-minted-in-subfiles) and [here](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/172).

At the moment, compiling `main.tex` using `chapter1/listing/pythonfile.py` within `\inputminted` succeeds, however this generates an error when I compile `chapter1.tex`. The curious thing is that compiling `chapter1.tex` using `./listing/pythonfile.py` has no effect on the output (the compilation seems to succeed bbut actually I do not notice any change in the .pdf output). ***Edit***: I found out that for some reason the automatic update of the pdf output does not work anymore using `minted`, problem observed also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417112/texstudio-no-preview-pdf-file-after-compiling-using-user-commands).

Is there a solution for this issue? If not, is there an alternative to `minted` that allows me to maintain the same project structure (and gives nice results with matlab and python codes possibly)? ***Edit***: The issue remained is the fact that I have to use two different arguments for the `inputminted` command when compiling `main.tex` and `chapter1.tex`.

Below my MWE.

`Main.tex`

```
\providecommand{\main}{.}
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage{subfiles}
\newcommand{\onlyinsubfile}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\notinsubfile}[1]{}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\biblio{\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}\bibliography{\main/bibgraf}}  % *Modification: added `\main/` to specify relative file location.

\graphicspath{{\main/figures/}}

\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption} % Centred captions

% Typesetting code
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\captionsetup[listing]{position=top}
\newenvironment{longlisting}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}

\begin{document}
    \def\biblio{}
\renewcommand{\onlyinsubfile}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\notinsubfile}[1]{#1}

Hallo main

\subfile{chapter1/chapter1}

\bibliographystyle{amsalpha} 
\bibliography{chapter1/bibgraf}
\end{document}
```

`chapter1.tex`

```
%!TeX root = chapter1
\providecommand{\main}{..}

\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{\main/}}
\makeatother

\documentclass[\main/main.tex]{subfiles}

\graphicspath{
    {"\main/chapter1/figures/"}
    {"\main/\main/chapter1/figures/"}
}


\begin{document}
%% my chapter 1 content
Hallo, this is a test:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:sec1:1}
\int dx =0 
\end{equation}

This is a figure test:
\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example.pdf}
\end{figure}

\onlyinsubfile{this only appears if chapter1.tex is compiled (not when main.tex is compiled)}
\notinsubfile{this only appears if main.tex is compiled (not when chapter1.tex is compiled)}

This is a reference test: \cite{anderson}

This is a listing test:
\begin{longlisting}
    \caption{Source code of \texttt{pythonfile.py}, where the main classes are defined.}
    \inputminted[frame=single,xleftmargin=\parindent,linenos,breaklines,breakafter=_(\{\[\]]{python}{./listings/pythonfile.py}
\end{longlisting}\vspace{2cm}

\onlyinsubfile{Call reference}
\biblio
%% 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `subfiles 2019/10/25 v1.4` is able to handle locally included files (like images). There should be no need anymore to modify input and graphics pathes. This probably does not solve your issues, but the code should become simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a recent version of the `subfiles` package (v1.3 2019/09/28 or later) you can fix the problem by defining a command `\subfix` in the preamble, like that:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\subfix[1]{\import@path#1}
\makeatother
```

Then, if some error message indicates that a file is searched in the wrong directory, wrap the command around the name of the file. E.g., write

```
\inputminted{python}{\subfix{./listings/pythonfile.py}}
```

instead of just `\inputminted{python}{./listings/pythonfile.py}`.

Here is a complete example with the following file structure:

```
main.tex
sub/sub.tex
sub/listings/prime.py
```

where the files have the following contents:

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\subfix[1]{\import@path#1}
\makeatother
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\subfile{sub/sub}
\end{document}

% sub/sub.tex
\documentclass[../main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\inputminted{python}{\subfix{listings/prime.py}}
\end{document}

% sub/listings/prime.py
def prime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    for i in range(2,n):
        if (n % i) == 0:
           return False
    return True
```

Running the command `pdflatex -shell-escape main.tex` in the main directory and `pdflatex -shell-escape sub.tex` in the subdirectory `sub` yields files `main.pdf` and `sub/sub.pdf`, respectively, both of which look like

[image]