# Using minted in subfiles in a subdirectory

Tags: minted, compilation-error, subfiles

[The answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/514264/41112) gives a MWE that shows how to make `\inputminted` work in a subfile. However, the approach does not work for `\begin{minted}`. For the following setup

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\subfile{sub/sub}
\end{document}
```

`sub/sub.tex`

```
\documentclass[../main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{python}
print("Hello2 world")
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

building `sub/sub.tex` in isolation (via overleaf) results in the error:

```
(./_minted-output/default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle) (./_minted-output/default.pygsty
le)
runsystem(pygmentize -l python -f latex -P commandprefix=PYG -F tokenmerge -o _
minted-output/ED80FDFC2E78B411DE97C895BDF46CCE50EF3049E275D339AF879205FC52C1A0.
pygtex output.pyg)...executed.


! Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was
probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need 
the outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool,
or may be using frozencache with a missing file.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.5 \end{minted}
                
This could be caused by using -output-directory or -aux-directory 
without setting minted's outputdir, or by using a build tool that 
changes paths in ways minted cannot detect, 
or using frozencache with a missing file.
```

Building `main.tex` seems to work fine in the MWE.

How can I make building `sub/sub.tex` work too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
% fix for first kind
\xpatchcmd\inputminted
  {\minted@pygmentize[#3]{#2}}
  {\minted@pygmentize[\import@path #3]{#2}}
  {}{\fail}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\subfile{sub/sub}
\end{document}
```

```
% sub/sub.tex
\documentclass[../main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{python}
print("Hello2 world")
\end{minted}

\inputminted{python}{./pythonfile.py} % a dummy python file located in sub/pythonfile.py
\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems to do the trick, but only if `xpatchcmd` is included after `subfiles`.

Comment: Is this a bug in one of the two packages in your opinion?

Comment: @Eric Kind of compatibility issue, but not bug. See similar issue between `minted` and `import` packages: https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/233.

Comment: This is no longer working for me; it seems to only work if you build the `main.tex` first; that is, `sub/sub.tex` is able to read from the cache, but it is not able to write to it.