# Error when running minted package on Windows 10

Tags: xetex, miktex, windows, minted

I'm getting the following error when trying to run minted package on tex file:

```
runsystem(for ^%i in (pygmentize.exe pygmentize.bat pygmentize.cmd) do set > Ma
sterThesis_CamiloCruz.aex <nul: /p x=^%~$PATH:i>> MasterThesis_CamiloCruz.aex).
..executed.

! Emergency stop.
<read 3> 

l.44 \begin{document}
                     ^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
```

I'm assuming the error has to be with minted package installation because when I comment the lines it successfully compiles:

```
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
    \usepackage{mdframed}
    \surroundwithmdframed{minted}
```

I already installed and updated all the packages from MikTeX, checked the proposed solutions from [How to use minted under MikTeX and Windows 7?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108661/how-to-use-minted-under-miktex-and-windows-7) and [How to install syntax highlight package minted on Windows 7?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23458/how-to-install-syntax-highlight-package-minted-on-windows-7)

I have already tried to use Python 2.7 installation with no results.

I also have installed Anaconda3 and edited the PATH system variable with `C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3` for Python 3.6 and  `C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\Scripts` for `pygmentize` (checked with CMD `pygmentize -h`).

I really don't know how to fix this problem since it was working fine before I reinstalled Windows OS. Any idea?

The latex content can be found here: https://pastebin.com/NPMq80Pm
and the error log here: https://pastebin.com/raw/VRpGNiKY

NOTE: I'm running TeXstudio 2.12.6, Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit) over Windows 10 (x64)

Comment: This may be a bug in the latest MiKTeX update. See https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/175.

Comment: @G.Poore Thanks a lot, I uninstalled MikTeX and installed TexLive and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [fixed](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2622/) in the latest MiKTeX release.  Just run the MiKTeX updater to get the latest version.