# pygments error Texstudio in Windows 10

Tags: texstudio, windows, python, pygments

I want to use minted package to highlighted my code block which is written in TexStudio. I installed minted package. Secondly I got error ***shell-escape-flag*** which is solved after research [How-to-invoke-latex-with-the-shell-escape-flag-in-texmakerx](https:////tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99475/how-to-invoke-latex-with-the-shell-escape-flag-in-texmakerx).

Now I got a new error. ***Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package. \begin{document}***

To solve this error I go through [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23458/how-to-install-syntax-highlight-package-minted-on-windows-7). There is a discussion about python installation. I installed ***Jet Brain Pycharm Community Edition 2017***. I was searching for ***pygmentize***. I got it C:\Users\Ellena\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages here. There is a folder name ***pygments***. After found this folder I think pygmentize already install in my system. Am I right?

How could I run my tex file? I am using Windows 10.

Comment: if you open a cmd window and type`pygmentize --help` then you should see some help text, if it says unknown command then it isn't installed and tex won't find it.

Comment: 'pygmentize' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. This is my output after run in cmd.